# Need help with UV Unwrapping of a Tyre

Tags: texturing, uv

I downloaded this model from Sketchfab, but the UVs are messed up. There are four tyres. I want to apply a texture to the rubber parts of the tyres. (Selected in image below)

[image]

This is the texture I want to apply:

[image]

The final result should look like this:

[image]

I tried projection from view, but it didn't turn out well. How do I go about it? Any idea will be appreciated.

Thankyou.

P.S: Since there are four tyres (two of them are different size than the other two), do I have to do the unwrapping separately for each of of them?

Comment: I would recommend watching a few tutorials on UV unwrapping. Youtube is full of them. Very basic workflow of marking seams and then unwrapping should work here. You could use [UvSquares](https://github.com/Radivarig/UvSquares) add-on to help you straighten the UV islands.

Comment: Thanks. I will look into it.
I did it using the "Follow active Quads" option and it seems to work.